# How to use shared runner (dind) for build stage and runner with shell executor on my server for deploy stage?

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab, continuous-deployment, gitlab-ci-runner

I want to do the build of my image on a shared runner and build it on gitlab registry.

then I want to pull that image, on my server using the runner on my server using shell executor.

but I face a problem, on my shell executor when i try to run a docker command, gives me this error

```
$ docker info
error during connect: Get http://docker:2375/v1.37/info: dial tcp: lookup docker on 172.31.0.2:53: no such host
```

here is my gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: docker:stable

services:
  - docker:dind

variables:
  CONTAINER_IMAGE: registry.gitlab.com/$CI_PROJECT_PATH
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

before_script:
  - docker info
  - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN registry.gitlab.com

build:
  stage: build
  script:
     - docker pull $CONTAINER_IMAGE:latest || true
     - docker build -f docker-images/web/Dockerfile --cache-from  $CONTAINER_IMAGE:latest --tag $CONTAINER_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA --tag $CONTAINER_IMAGE:latest .
     - docker push $CONTAINER_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
     - docker push $CONTAINER_IMAGE:latest

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - docker pull $CONTAINER_IMAGE:latest || true
  tags:
    - deploy
    - shell
```

I tested without the build stage, and comented the variables DOCKER_HOST and services docker:dind, and works. Execute the docker commands and works well.

I'm new on this, i think the problem is that my shell executor tries to comunicate with the docker  host tcp://docker:2375, and not my docker engine.

What can I do?. I was thinking on call a shell script, and run the docker commands on this script. But I would like to do it directly on my gitlab-ci.yml

Comment: Could you add the log? Without it, it will be hard to answer the question. Please edit the Q&A and let us know when it can be reviewed. In the mean time the question will be closed.